# How to trigger an event handler before the page is reloaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I have a control and Event Handler:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SortDirection1" runat="server" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="SortDirection_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0"> ASC </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1"> DESC </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and

```
protected void SortDirection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var DDL = (sender as DropDownList);
    Session["SortDirection"] = DDL.SelectedIndex;
}
```

If I change selection in DropDownList, page will be reloaded and only after it this handler will be triggered. So, there is a problem. I try to use `Session["SortDirection"]` before it will be rewrited. The question is How to rewrite `Session["SortDirection"]` before page reloading?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but you can't change the asp.net web forms page life cycle.  The page_load event will always run before the the control event handlers fire.  If you want code to run after the event handlers run then you need to hook into a different event in the page lifecycle such as load_complete

Comment: @Ben Robinson, I need to run some code after user changed value In DropDownList, but I need to use some results of this code in page_init event handler.

Comment: You simply can't do that, page_init runs before the event handler fires., you can't even check the values of any controls as they are not loaded yet. You could check the value of the control in page_load, but you won't be able to tell whether it has changed.  See this article for the page lifecycle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: @Ben Robinson, ОК. Is there another way to refresh page with new parameters, that user selected form DropDownList?

Comment: Yes, but not in the page_init.  If you want to use the values from the controls it needs to be in an event that happens after the init event.

Comment: @Ben Robinson, can I do this in Page_load event? Which is the earliest event from which I can get control's value?

Comment: Yes page_load will work fine.  You won't now if the value has changed, but I am not sure how important that is to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an autopostback on the DDL and then setting a session value in the **Selected Index Changed** event. The correct place to use that value is in the **Load Complete** event. That event gets fired after the Selected Index Change event.

It is very beneficial to learn the [complete ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx).  There is a nice diagram in the "*Additional Page Life Cycle Considerations*" section that shows the events and methods for the page and its controls. The Selected Index Change event happens in Event Handling section.

The Load Complete happens after that. This gets raised when all of the process has been completed and just before the rendering starts. The purpose of the Load Complete is to give you a place for logic once all of the setup and processing is finished.